# Atlassian Plugin SDK & JIRA Software

Tags: maven, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I installed and got running the atlassian plugin sdk (6.1.0). However whenever I start JIRA, I am only able to get JIRA Core. How do I get JIRA Software as well?

I found this that seems to answer what I need, but I'm pretty confused as where to make this change:
https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configure-amps-to-run-jira-core-with-additional-applications-installed

I tried to grep the string `<artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>` and to throw in the `configuration` tag given in that url in the files that made sense to put it in that came up within `~/.m2`, `amps-standalone/` and `Atlassian/atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.1.0`. No luck though.

Any suggestions on how to always load JIRA Software whenever I do an `atlas-run` and/or an `atlas-run-standalone --product jira` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should edit your plugin's `pom.xml` according to your link - you will find `<artifactId>maven-jira-plugin</artifactId>` there.

Or otherwise start with JIRA Core and install JIRA Software/JIRA ServiceDesk applications via Applications at JIRA Admin - they will be kept between restarts unless you issue `atlas-clean` command.